# strstr function misundersandings

Tags: c++, strstr

There is a problem with strstr function. I have tried to compile password program, but it falls. Any help would be highly appreciated

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    char s[5], password[]="kuku";
    int i,k=0;
    for (i=0; !k && i<3;i++){
        printf("\ enter password: \n");
        gets(s);
        if (strstr(s.password[])) k=1;
    }

    if(k) printf("password accepted");
    else printf("password not accepted");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't use `gets`.  It has been removed from both the current C and C++ standards. Besides the `using namespace std;`, your code looks like straight C code.  If you are actually in a C++ course I would be worried as this is not what C++, or Modern C++ looks like.

Comment: @Torebek Zhumabek Specifying this construction  password[] as a function argument is wrong.

Comment: _"...but it falls..."_: How does it fail?

Comment: `strstr` takes two arguments, and s.password[] is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

> if (strstr(s.password[])) k=1;

What did you want to accomplish with this? strstr() needs two arguments (haystack and needle, meaning that you want to find the needle in the haystack). You only pass one argument, which is wrong.

The correct code will be something like:

```
if (strstr(s, password) != NULL) k=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

In this expression

```
strstr(s.password[])
```

there are two errors. The first one is that the separator of arguments is comma while you are using a dot.

The second one is that instead of the construction `password[]` you have to use the expression `password`

Take into account that the function `strstr` is not suitable to check whether two strings are equal each other. It is better to use function `strcmp`.

And the function `gets` is not supported by the C standard. Use instead function `fgets`.

And as you are trying to compile the program as a C++ program then use the standard class `std::string` instead of raw character arrays.